# Is it possible to design an over/under AC voltage protection circuit using only diodes and SCRs?

Tags: ac, zener, over-voltage-protection, scr, undervoltage

Is it possible to design a circuit using only SCRs and diodes (Zener or otherwise) as a main regulating device to protect a load (220 V, 80 W) from over- and undervoltage? Other passive components (resistors, capacitors, DIACs, TRIACs, etc.) can be used.

Comment: So essentially the question is "is it possible to implement over- and undervoltage protection without dedicated ICs?"?
What over- and undervoltages are you concerned about? Do you need to protect against spikes, is it high/low Vpeak, or do you only care about RMS?

Comment: @MrGerber Yes, exactly, without using any dedicated ICs and Yes, only the RMS voltage is of concern

Comment: The answer is yes. Pretty much anything is possible, but is it an appropriate or good solution? We cannot answer that. It depends on your application specifications.
You need to think about what you consider to be too high voltage, too low voltage - how quickly should the circuit respond, are there any constraints for cost, size, efficiency etc.